# Find every row that matches keyword, then paste all rows with keyword found

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to find every time a person's name is found within a range, then copy and paste that range. My code only works for the first time a person's name is found and only copies that row, instead of all rows they are in. Please let me know how to edit my code to fix this.

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

    Dim myValue As String
    myEmp = InputBox("Search for an employee by last name")
    ActiveSheet.Range("B2").Value = myEmp

    Dim lastrow As Long
    lastrow = Worksheets("Employee Reports").Range("A65536").End(xlUp).Row

    With Sheet7
        Dim rw As Range
        Set rw = .Range("B:B").Find(What:=myEmp, After:=.Range("B1"), _
        LookIn:=xlFormulas, LookAt:=xlWhole, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, _
        SearchDirection:=xlNext, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False)

        If Not rw Is Nothing Then
            rw.EntireRow.Copy Worksheets("Employee Reports").Cells(5, 1)
        Else
            MsgBox myEmp & "Employee Not Found"
        End If
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Does the next instance go in `cells(6,1)` etc?

Comment: Yes - it won't let me comment just three words so I'm adding this as well

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this. The standard way, which is well documented by the way, is to store the address of the first found cell, and then keep looking for the next instance until you are back to the original address.

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

Dim myValue As String, s As String, r As Long

myEmp = InputBox("Search for an employee by last name")
ActiveSheet.Range("B2").Value = myEmp 'better to specify sheet
r = 5

Dim lastrow As Long
lastrow = Worksheets("Employee Reports").Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row 'don't hard-code the row number

With Sheet7 'would be better to stick to all names or all code names rather than mixing
    Dim rw As Range
    Set rw = .Range("B:B").Find(What:=myEmp, After:=.Range("B1"), LookIn:=xlFormulas, _
                                LookAt:=xlWhole, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, _
                                MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False)
    If Not rw Is Nothing Then
        s = rw.Address
        Do
            rw.EntireRow.Copy Worksheets("Employee Reports").Cells(r, 1)
            r = r + 1
            Set rw = .Range("B:B").FindNext(rw)
        Loop Until rw.Address = s
    Else
        MsgBox myEmp & "Employee Not Found"
    End If
End With

End Sub
```

Comment: It keeps giving me an error that method or data member not found for `.Find`

Comment: Accidentally deleted the range - try it now.